# How to wait for a function to complete before executing another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm using [selecter jquery](http://formstone.it/components/Selecter/demo/index.html). I initialize it by typing the code

```
$("select").selecter();
```

I need to make sure that the formstone selecter jquery library has completed before i start appending elements. So what i did is to is use the `$.when` function

```
initialize: function(){
    $.when($("select").selecter()).then(this.initOptions());
},

initOptions: function(){
    this.$el.find('.selecter').addClass('something');
}
```

But this does not work. How can i wait while formstone selecter is doing its thing before i execute another function?

Thanks,

**UPDATE**

Here's the update of what i did but it does not work.

```
initialize: function(){
   $("select").selecter({callback: this.initOptions });
},

initOptions: function(){
    this.$el.find('.selecter').addClass('something');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a callback option.

> The function passed as a callback will receive the newly selected value as the first parameter

Should be `$("select").selecter(callback: function() { alert('callback fired.') });`
or as shown

```
$("select").selecter({
    callback: selectCallback
});

function selectCallback(value, index) {
    alert("VALUE: " + value + ", INDEX: " + index);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm still new to javascript. How can i use it? can you provide more info?

Comment: the second examples shows just this - how to use it. Just write any function and pass its name as a parameter on init time $("select").selecter({ callback: selectCallback  });

Answer (score 0):

The problem which I think regarding the callback edited code is that this can refer to anything. Try the following code

```
var selectorObj = {
 initialize: function(){
    $("select").selecter({callback: selectorObj.initOptions });
    },
initOptions: function(){
    this.$el.find('.selecter').addClass('something');
     }
};
```

Created a working fiddler for you http://jsfiddle.net/6Bj6j/

The css is out of shape. Just select what is poping up when you click on the dropdown. You will get an alert which is written in the callback.

Comment: I'm getting 

SyntaxError: missing : after property id


var selectorObj = {

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the provided snippet is the scope of the callback:

```
var selectorObj = {
    initialize: function(){
        $("select").selecter({ callback: selectorObj.initOptions });
    },
    initOptions: function(){
        // 'this' refers to the "$('.selecter')" jQuery element
        this.addClass('something');
    }
};
```

However if you just need to add a class to the rendered element, you should use the 'customClass' option:

```
$("select").selecter({
    customClass: "something"
});
```

If you need to do more, you can always access the Selecter element directly:

```
var $selecter = $("select").selecter().next(".selecter");

$selecter.addClass("something").find(".selecter-selected").trigger("click");
```

Sidenote: I'm the main developer of Formstone. If you have any suggestions for new features or better implementation, just open a new issue on GitHub.