# In Javascript how to wait for a function with ajax call to completer before continuing with another function

Tags: javascript, ajax

Here is an over view of my js file where I am calling 2 function foo1 and foo2.

```
function foo1(){
 // do some ajax call which takes random amount of time
}

function foo2(){
 // do something which needs foo1() being already  done
}

foo1();
// reach here only if foo1 is complete
foo2();
```

ps. I dont want to use jQuery or knockout. 
Also have already looked into [How to wait for a func...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21772834/how-to-wait-for-a-function-to-complete-before-executing-another-function)

Comment: you don't have to do anything. function calls in JS block. it's not multi-threaded. unless foo1() is doing an ajax call or something, foo2() will **NOT** get called until foo1() returns.

Comment: @MarcB Thank you I added ajax call being part of foo1. Appreciated your comment

Comment: then you have the `success:` handler in the ajax stuff call `foo2()` when the ajax results get returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you say foo1() is doing ajax, you'd need something like this:

```
function foo1() { 
   $.ajax( ....
       success: function() { foo2(); }
   );
}
function foo2() {
    console.log("foo1() finished");
}

foo1();
```

So when the ajax call returns (successfully), it'll automatically call foo2(), and the only thing you need to do is call foo1().